# Pourquoi des lieux nommés "la crotte"

Tags: étymologie

J'ai vu une rue qui s’appelait « la crotte », donc j'ai regardé l'odonymie de ce mot et il parait qu'il y a au moins deux cents endroits nommés la crotte, les crottes, et d'autres variantes trop vulgaires pour un site comme celui-ci.

Pourquoi y a-t-il de tels noms de rues ? J'aurai plutôt opté pour la jonquille et l’érable, donc je ne comprends pas quelle est l'étymologie et la raison de ce nom de rue.

Answer (score 8):

> ...et d'autres variantes trop vulgaires pour un site comme ceci.

Aucune variante n'est trop vulgaire pour FSE tant qu'il s'agit de faire référence à du vocabulaire et pas à s'invectiver. Qui plus est, *crotte* (*poop, dung*), contrairement à *merde* par exemple, n'est pas vulgaire en français.

> quelle est l'étymologie et la culture de ce nom de rue ?

L'étymologie de la plupart des noms de lieux comportant le mot *crotte*, en particulier dans le midi de la France, est simple. Ce mot [vient du grec *κρυπτη* via le latin *crypta*](https://www.geneanet.org/genealogie/crotte/CROTTE) (passage souterrain, caverne) qui a donné en français les doublons *grotte* et *crypte*.

Voir par exemple ce quartier de Marseille: [Les crottes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Crottes).

Ce mot n'est pas lié à l'autre *crotte* d'origine germanique:

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/crotte) :

> Prob. de l'a. b. frq. *krotta à déduire du rhénan krotz « brique mal moulée; épaisse motte de terre; fruit rabougri; reste » (le sens primitif étant « excrément globuleux »; cf. le m. angl. crote « petit morceau, fragment », NED) plutôt que du m. néerl. krotte « boue déposée sur les vêtements » non attesté av. 1599 (ce sens secondaire étant peut-être dû au fr. largement antérieur),

En revanche, si la rue fait référence à un cours d'eau nommé *roule-crotte*, il s'agit alors bien de ce deuxième sens (Dictionnaire topographique, historique et statistique de la Sarthe):

[image]

Comment: Je voulais éviter de mentionner le lieu appellé roule-crotte, ce qui s'appareille au sense celte et provençal de boule. Selon votre étymologie, les centaines d'endroits nommés pisse viennent de la pie de la vache?! pisse renard, pisse beuf, pisse viellie, pisse loup, pissevin, pissebaque, pisselievre... Selon le motif d'odonymie, l'étymologie de krypta semble irréel ou fantastique.

Comment: N'extrapole pas. Je n'ai jamais parlé de l'étymologie de roule-crotte ni de pisse-quelque chose.

Comment: J'ai mis un vote positif pour l'originalité de l'idée, sans y croire pour autant! si vous voulez nier le contexte agriculturel démontré par les lieux nommés pisse, ce serait simpliste. il y a des variantes trop vulgaires visiblement! les mots se sont différenciées il y a 400 ans, bien après que les rues rurales soient crées, donnant assez de temps de rectifier les lieux bénis de krypte et les crotte avec deux "t" dans les cadastres... et les lieux, campagnards, datent souvent d'après .. la bonne réponse c'est que les noms datent d'un temps plus innocent et agriculturel.

Comment: 1. Tu peux me tutoyer.  2. L'idée n'est pas originale (de moi) mais c'est l'étymologie établie de nombreux lieux utilisant le mot crotte. 3. Je ne nie rien du tout. Si tu veux poser une question sur *pisse-xxx*, n'hésite pas mais ne considère pas que ce que j'ai répondu pour *crotte* a un lien quelconque avec cette autre question. 4. Il n'est pas impossible qu'il y ait des rues nommées *rue de la crotte* où il s'agit vraiment d'excréments. C'est cependant improbable. 5. La ville/région où tu as trouvé cette rue a son importance, *cròta* étant un mot provençal/occitan ayant aussi les deux sens.

Comment: Je viens de comprendre ton premier commentaire. Si le lieu s'appelle **roule-crotte**, l'étymologie est bien sûr différente. Il fallait le préciser dans la question (que tu peux éditer).

Answer (score 2):

En complément à la réponse de @jlliagre, je te conseille d'aller faire un tour sur le site **[Paristique](https://www.paristique.fr)** qui recense l'histoire et l'origine du nom des rues de Paris. Tu y apprends par exemple que la **rue Brisemiche** tient son nom :

> aux pains que l'on distribuait aux chanoines de la collégiale Saint-Merri.

Tu as aussi cet **[article](https://legarsvoyage.com/2020/03/29/ces-noms-de-rues-insolites/)** qui recense quelques-uns des noms de rues francophones les plus insolites et explique leur origine.
Ce qu'il dit confirme d'ailleurs la réponse de @jlliagre :

> A Marseille, la rue des Crottes devrait son origine au mot provençal « croto » qui veut dire cave ou souterrain.

Mais il y a aussi d'autres choses intéressantes :

> La rue de la Gerbe (à Lyon) qui devrait son nom à une enseigne qui était représentée par trois personnages en train de tenir des gerbes de blé.

**En général, on se rend compte qu'il y a un lien avec quelque chose de courant, non-vulgaire.**